# Ubuntu Server 12.04 misnamed user account during setup

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-server

If I accidentally misnamed my user account during the initial installation, for example if I type "devdmin" instead of "devadmin", is there a way to change that account username?

The reason I ask is because I created an ubuntu server VM on VirtualBox, and when I mounted a shared folder, it says it belongs to my misnamed initial user account, e.g. "devdmin". Now I have to use sudo to edit any of the files within the shared folder, using my second account that I correctly named. I tried using `chown -R devadmin sharedfolder` and `chgrp -R devadmin sharedfolder` but it does not do anything. When I run `ls -lah`, it shows `devdmin` as the owner and group of those files.

Answer (score 2):

You can rename your userid with the `usermod` commnand.  More [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-howto-rename-user-account/).